# Error: A delegating constructor cannot have other mem-initializers

Tags: c++, class, constructor, constructor-overloading

I have the class as follows:

```
class A{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
public:
    A(int a1){
        a1 >= 0 ? a = a1 : a = -1;
    }
    A(int a1, int b1, int c1) : A{ a1 }, b{ b1 }, c{ c1 } {} //<---------- this line gives the error
};
```

but this gives me the error "A delegating constructor cannot have other mem-initializers".

I ended up fixing the code and making it:

```
class A{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
public:
    A(int a1){
        a1 >= 0 ? a = a1 : a = -1;
    }
    A(int a1, int b1, int c1) : A{ a1 } {
        b = b1;
        c = c1;
    }
};
```

And the error went away. My question is, WHY does this make the error go away? Why does the previous method not work?

Comment: Do you understand what a "delegating constructor" is?  Your `A{ a1 }` is expected to _completely_ initialize the object.  That's something the language expects.

Comment: For an `int`, it doesn't matter whether you initialize it in the member init list or assign in the constructor body. It will make more sense if you plop an actual class in there, and instrument its constructors and assignment operators. The member init list calls the constructors for all members (if they're of class types, that is), one way or another. Each member can have its constructor called at most once. Delegating with `: A{...}` indirectly calls every member's constructor, so you can't call more constructors with `, b{...}, c{...}`.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by others in comments, the reason is that this is how the language specification is defined. That's why you can get a compiler error with a helpful message describing the cause of the problem.

From [[class.base.init]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.init#class.base.init-6):

> [6.](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.init#class.base.init-6) ... If a [mem-initializer-id](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.init#nt:mem-initializer-id) designates the constructor's class, it shall be the only [mem-initializer](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.init#nt:mem-initializer); the constructor is a *delegating constructor*, and the constructor selected by the [mem-initializer](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.init#nt:mem-initializer) is the *target constructor*...

Now, as for your delegating constructor, I propose that you currently have this backwards. The constructor `A(int)` is in fact a short-hand for your otherwise complete version `A(int, int, int)`. It makes more sense to delegate in the other direction, assuming you don't have a very special reason to not initialize `b` and `c` at all:

```
class A
{
    int a, b, c;

public:
    A(int a) : A(a, 0, 0) {}

    A(int a, int b, int c)
        : a{a >= 0 ? a : -1}
        , b{b}
        , c{c}
    {}
};
```

Note also that you don't need to add random suffixes to your identifiers in an attempt to avoid name collisions. See the following:

From [[class.base.init]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.init#class.base.init):

> [2.](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.init#class.base.init-2) Lookup for an unqualified name in a [mem-initializer-id](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.init#nt:mem-initializer-id) ignores the constructor's function parameter scope.
>
> [15.](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.init#class.base.init-15) [Note [7](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.init#class.base.init-note-7): The [expression-list](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post.general#nt:expression-list) or [braced-init-list](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#nt:braced-init-list) of a [mem-initializer](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.init#nt:mem-initializer) is in the function parameter scope of the constructor and can use `this` to refer to the object being initialized.
> *— end note*]

In short, `a{a >= 0 ? a : -1}` initializes the member `a`, and all the `a` identifiers inside the initializer list refer to the function parameter `a`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
```

Okay, so an `A` contains an `a`, a `b`, and a `c`.

```
    A(int a1, int b1, int c1) : A{ a1 }, b{ b1 }, c{ c1 } {} //<---------- this line gives the error
```

After `A{ a1 }`, you've initialized an `A`. Since an `A` contains an `a`, a `b`, and a `c`, initializing an `A` means we've already initialized an `a`, a `b`, and a `c`. So why are you trying to initialize `b` and `c` a second time? What would that do?